# Why would one environment use "+" instead of "%20" for spaces when using url_encode filter?

Tags: templating

I just uploaded some templates to the server and discovered that some of my url encoded strings are being output with a "+" for spaces instead of the "%20" that is desired. It is fine in my local environment. Any ideas?

According to the [twig encode_url documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html) `url_encode` now uses php's `rawurlencode` by default:

> Internally, Twig uses the PHP urlencode (or rawurlencode if you pass true as the first parameter) or the http_build_query function. Note that as of Twig 1.16.0, urlencode always uses rawurlencode (the raw argument was removed.)

I have also tried passing 'true' as the first parameter just in case. No luck.

Comment: What PHP versions are on the server and locally?

Comment: @Brad local 5.5.14; server 5.3.5

Comment: Was thinking maybe it's a PHP change in behavior/bug fix, but not seeing anything here http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Comment: If you test `url_encode()` directly from a PHP script with the same string, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @BradBell Sorry, I'm not sure how to call `url_encode()` from php. Is there a craft helper function available? Or do you mean php's `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()`? Both of those act as expected on both the server and local. urlencode returns '+' and rawurlencode returns '%20'.

Comment: Yeah... sorry. I meant PHP's `urlencode()`. Craft 2.2 is using Twig 1.16.0, so it should be using PHP's `rawurlencode()`. Will have to think on it some more.

Comment: @BradBell I think I got it — The filter is actually using `http_build_query` when params are passed as an array, which was changed in php 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the twig `url_encode` filter uses the php function `http_build_query` if parameters are passed to it as an array. i.e. `{'key':'value', 'key':'value'}|url_encode`. Otherwise it uses `rawurlencode`.

`http_build_query` was modified in php 5.4 to include a new property `enc_type`, that allowed you to specify that it use `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986`encoding (which is also what `rawurlencode` uses).

The `url_encode` filter is defined in `craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php` on line 596, and contains a clause to make it backwards compatible with php 5.3, but you obviously will loose the encoding type.

Options are: upgrade php to 5.4+; do not pass params as an array to the `url_encode` filter; or do a string replace on the encoded string.

Comment: I was just going to say that! ;)